# Unit testing an API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class and a method which looks like this

```
class A {
  private RetryLogic logic;
  private Service serviceClient; 
  public A(){
    logic = new RetryLogic();
    serviceClient = new Service();
  }

  public Response methodA() {
    Request request = new Request();
    serviceClient.addRetryLogic(logic);
    Responce response = serviceClient.call(request);
    return response; 
  }
}
```

The retry logic in this case will retry the service call if there is a failure like Service not available or any HTTP error.

But it won't retry if the service is getting called and throwing any modeled exceptions.

If I am writing a unit test for methodA is it appropriate (or should I be concerned) to test the retry logic by adding a test which would mock an HTTP exception and check if the retry works ?

The RetryLogic is basically a different package not owned by me.

Comment: Sure, you can annotate the test like this in JUnit: @Test(expected=AnyKindOfException.class)

Comment: Yeah, I can try to test it, but my question is should I really be concerned about testing this because it is a method in a package not owned by me.?

Comment: It depends on how much you trust the provider of the package and how much risk there is if an issue is discovered in production. It is your job to recommend whether or not to test it, to whoever is paying for the testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you test the `setConnectionTimeout` of the `Apache Commons HttpClient`? or the `setAutoCommit` of your `JDBC Client`? I wouldn't.

If you trust that `Service` as you trust the rest of your dependencies, it makes no sense to test it. Just imagine that there are 1000 developers using `Service`, and all of them are testing the retry functionality... it's a bit of waste of time, isn't it?